# "only D registers may be indexed -- `strb r0 [r1],#1" when trying to store a normal register

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7

I'm trying to store a byte into memory with post-increment addressing, with

```
strb r0 [r1],#1
```

Assembling the program containing this line produces the console error

> only D registers may be indexed -- `strb r0 [r1],#1"

Comment: You are missing a comma. Probably just misleading error message.

Comment: Note that you receive this error during *assembly,* not during *execution.*  Make sure to use correct terms as to not confuse others.

Comment: @Jester: Does NEON have syntax like `d0[1]` or something?  So the error message applies, but yeah in a non-obvious way when you don't realize the comma is missing, and weren't trying to use `[]` on r0.  Given the error message, there might be some future value in answering this, since people with the same typo can find it via the fairly unique error message.  Or the comment is probably enough, google will probably still send them here.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, it seems so: e.g. `vmov.8 d3[4], r2`.